# How to use lambda as method within a class?

Tags: python

Here is what I am trying to do

```
class BaseClass(object):
    successify = lambda x: "<Success>%s</Success>" % x
    errorify = lambda x: "<Error>%s</Error>" % x
    def try1(self):
        print successify("try1")
    def try2(self):
        print self.successify("try2")
```

But neither of the methods seem to work..

```
>>> BaseClass().try1()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 5, in try1
NameError: global name 'successify' is not defined
>>> BaseClass().try2()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 7, in try2
TypeError: <lambda>() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)
```

How do I use lambdas as methods within a class?

Comment: Please *don't*; using `def successify(self, x): return "<Success>%s</Success>" % x` has more metadata, reads more nicely and takes *only 3 more characters*.

Comment: @Veedrac That's what I used eventually, and precisely for the same reasons. This was more of a stumbled upon situation where I couldn't figure out why the lambdas were not working. FWIW, I was half expecting this to not being supported and wanted to find relevant reasons, if any.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use `lambda self, x: "...%s..." % x`

Answer (score 19):

You have few possibilities of using/accessing class variables of lambdas. Three of them are:

```
class BaseClass(object):
    successify = lambda x: "<Success>%s</Success>" % x
    errorify = lambda x: "<Error>%s</Error>" % x
    def try1(self):
        print(self.__class__.successify("try1"))
    def try2(self):
        print(self.__class__.successify("try2"))

 # or 

class BaseClass(object):
    successify = lambda x: "<Success>%s</Success>" % x
    errorify = lambda x: "<Error>%s</Error>" % x
    def try1(self):
        print(BaseClass.successify("try1"))
    def try2(self):
        print(BaseClass.successify("try2"))

# or Please not changes to lambda definitions below

class BaseClass(object):
    successify = lambda self,x: "<Success>%s</Success>" % x
    errorify = lambda self,x: "<Error>%s</Error>" % x
    def try1(self):
        print(self.successify("try1"))
    def try2(self):
        print(self.successify("try2"))
```

Comment: first two approaches are for python3, and last works in python2.

Comment: @VishnuUpadhyay Thx. Should have checked this in python 2. Usually I work with python 3, and keep forgetting that some things dont work in python 2.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access `successify` as object function then first argument is `self` means object instance.

you have to change your lambada function if you have to use `self.successify`

```
successify = lambda self, x: "<Success>%s</Success>" % x
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, [Marcin's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27244163/5337834) first answer doesn't work in Python 2. To recap, he wrote

```
class BaseClass(object):
    successify = lambda x: "<Success>%s</Success>" % x
    errorify = lambda x: "<Error>%s</Error>" % x
    def try1(self):
        print(self.__class__.successify("try1"))
    def try2(self):
        print(self.__class__.successify("try2"))
```

But this doesn't work in Python 2. An interesting trick would be to make the class believe it is a static method instead of a static variable. After changing the code suitably, it becomes:

```
class BaseClass(object):
    successify = staticmethod(lambda x: "<Success>%s</Success>" % x)
    errorify = staticmethod(lambda x: "<Error>%s</Error>" % x)
    def try1(self):
        print(self.__class__.successify("try1")) # Works!
    def try2(self):
        print(self.__class__.successify("try2")) # Works!
```